# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

Why I cannot convert String value from the JSON response to Int? It returns me the next error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(JSON)'
```

When I try to:

```
Int(json[i]["id"])
```

How can I convert it to Int?

Comment: Where does `json` come from, of what type is it?

Comment: @luk2302 it comes as Integer, but in logs I see it as: `"id" : "48"`

Comment: `swiftyJSON` solves the problem

Comment: That is not what I was asking, show us the lines where you assign and define `json` - what is the log that you showed there? Is that `json` or `json[i]`?

Comment: @aaisataev no it doesn't.

Comment: @luk2302 `Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).validate().responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .Success:
                        if let value = response.result.value {
                            let json = JSON(value) print(json)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/README.md#optional-getter).

In that case you have two options:

**The optional getter:**

```
if let id = json[i]["id"].int {
   // do something
}
```

**The non optional getter:**

```
let id: Int = json[i]["id"].intValue
```